# Multiple robots in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a simulated robot in Gazebo that comes from a urdf.xacro
I expect to have multiple copies of it.

The thing is that I want to change the origin of my robots not manually (when I launch them). I know that there is a tag inside the robot.urdf.xacro file that specifies the origin, but I want to know if there is any parameter which I can modify without having to rewrite the urdf file.

Can you help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174173/multiple-robots-in-gazebo/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi arenillas, does this post answer your question: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4190/how-do-you-run-multiple-hector_quadrotors-without/  ?

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2014-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-06-23**:
It was just what I was looking for.
Thanks